# comment connect to a site with curl

Tags: php, forms, authentication, curl

I try to connect at my website with curl. I have a form with login and password.

but that dont work, maybe i forget a step ?

my code :

```
$url = "https://www.mywebsite/login.php";

$ch2 = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
$timeout = 30;
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,         10); 
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,  $timeout );


curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch2,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"
    $data = "
    hardkey=obligatoire
    &login=HERM
    &password=xxxx
    &x=41
    &y=14";
");     


$result = curl_exec($ch2);
```

but normaly i have redirect to https://www.mywebsite/apercu.php, but currently no .. why ?

Thank you for your help :)

Edit:

the syntahxe is :

```
$data = "
hardkey=obligatoire
&login=HERM
&password=xxxx
&x=41
&y=14";
```

i see it when i look network with action login.php

Comment: Can you share the code of your login page? is it using POST or GET?

Comment: its POST i edit my post

Comment: The data doesn't look like valid POST data, why this `$data = ".."` in the string? Just pass an array with the postfields, as described in the documentation of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS...